# Who was the first śūdra to be born or appear on Earth?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins, varna, kshatriya, shudra

Who was the first śūdra (or the śūdra-couple) to be *born*?

Likewise, who was the first brāhmaṇa, the first kṣatriya and vaiśya to be *born*?

Some might argue, the first śūdra could not have been *born* because that would make his/her parents also śūdra and then they would become the first śūdras. So we end up with an infinite regress. To avoid this problem, assume the first śūdra (or the śūdra-couple) just appeared on Earth and were not borne of a womb, then the question becomes: Who was the first śūdra (brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, etc.) to appear on Earth?

---

**[Note](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1483)**: This question assumes the caste-system to be birth-based, so I'm not looking for answers/comments that argue that varṇa is guṇa-based or varṇa is independent of birth.

Comment: Who as in by name?

Comment: Yes, by name. Imagine a śūdra drawing his genealogy/ancestry chart, who's the first person on this chart?

Comment: I don't even think the scripture records such a fact.

Comment: your question also assumes that whatever is the birth-based varna, that remains the same throughout his life. It is possible to downgrade very easily i.e lose Brahmana-tvam. That's why we repeatedly say 'birth' is necessary but not sufficient, guna & karma are also necessary (for 99.99% of cases, rare exceptions of upgrading varna by tapa/guna/karma do exist). So, a brahmana (or kshatryia/vaishya) who fell down from his path and became Sudra, may have been the first Sudra and then sired the first 'birth-Sudra', starting off the chain. You need not assume that they were not born of a womb.

Comment: @ram The only assumption I'm making is that the first few people in each varṇa are born without any intermixing/loss of castes (they just appeared). But if you think the first śūdra was not born but a brāhmaṇa became one because he lost his caste, that's a valid answer if you can find a source. Then the question becomes: Who is the first of the brāhmaṇas and who was the first that became a śūdra?

Answer (score 4):

The first Shudras were created in the beginning of Treta yuga based on their quality of Tamas.

The Vayu Purana says:

> "The Váyu goes farther than this, and states that the castes were now
>   first divided according to their occupations; having, indeed,
>   previously stated that there was no such distinction in the Krita age:
>   'Brahmá now appointed those who were robust and violent to be
>   Kshetriyas, to protect the rest; those who were pure and pious he made
>   Brahmans; those who were of less power, but industrious, and addicted
>   to cultivate the ground, he made Vaisyas; whilst the feeble and poor
>   of spirit were constituted Śúdras: and he assigned them their several
>   occupations, to prevent that interference with one another which had
>   occurred as long as they recognised no duties peculiar to castes."

So, there was no caste division in Krta Yuga because everyone was pure, and then by the beginning of Treta yuga, humans underwent changes and started exhibiting different tendencies, so Brahma divided humanity based on their inherent guna.

Comment: Can you also add the link to the source from which you're quoting? "so Brahma divided humanity based on their inherent guna" - so suddenly a group of people all became śūdras? How big was this group? And the rest (brāhmaṇas, kṣatriyas, etc.) suddenly started wearing yajñopavītas and came to be identified as dvijas? Was each of the śūdra told in person by Brahma that he/she was a śūdra?

Comment: @sv. On this page under footnote number 9: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp040.htm

Comment: Manu Smriti the Smriti to be particularly applicable in Krita clearly talks about caste system.. so what's up? @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Ikshvaku for me all castes are equally divine. I meditate on Shivji, and I would never think of differentiating between his legs or head. He's pure everywhere, everything comes from him and is destined to go in him. Therefore, it is human duty to serve all beings, since they come from the most divine source and have the divine in them.

Comment: based on their guna--- but you say in ur other posts that it's based on birth..

Comment: @YDS He divided based on guna of the body, not of the mind.

Comment: so u mean one cannot become stronger or weaker over time..

Comment: @YDS They can, but that doesn't determine varna. Guna composition of the sthula sharira does.

Comment: Cells also divide, cell division is beginning of biology, there are different kinds of cells who do different duties, imagine how absurd, chaos it'd be if an mentally senile imbecile like evil jew, declared all cells poseess a fictional thing such as cellity, are equal, and made stupid court system to enforce 'justice' .

Comment: Sir in Satya Yuga only one Varna was there? Even Mahabharata + Bhagavata says it. So now Purusha Sukta was composed in Treta Yuga? Please tell sir !

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Vedas themselves were composed in Treta yuga. This is said in the Smritis themselves. In Krta yuga there was only one Veda, the holy pranava. Then in treta yuga, the pranava manifested into shabda-rupa, the Vedas. Then at the end of dwapara yuga, Vyasa divided the one Veda into four parts: rk, yajus, sAman, and atharva (which has all the other 3).

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru The AtharvAngirasa Veda is a Veda compiled by Atharvan and Angirasa, that consists of rks, samans, and yajus. Those are the 3 verse types. Atharva-angirasa are the names of two rishis. Saman is just a rk set into musical intonation. Yajus is prose.

Comment: Sir then why do we say Vedas are Eternal? Even 4 Varnas were manifested in Treta Yuga so when all Bramhins were there in Satya Yuga what did they do?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru "Sir then why do we say Vedas are Eternal?" - Mimamsakas and Vedantins think that the Vedic sentences are literally eternal. I think that is absurd. The Vedas themselves say they were created by Rishis based on their perception of Brahman, plus that is the more rational conclusion. So, any scripture that says "eternal Veda" means that some text called "Vedas" is created every kalpa by Rishis, or that the vedic knowledge is eternal.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru "so when all Bramhins were there in Satya Yuga what did they do?" - They did tapas, etc. HOWEVER, the Brahmanas who became rajasic, became kshatriyas, those Brahmanas who became rajas/tamas, become Vaishyas, etc.

Comment: Sir yourself are a Vedantin right? Thanks for clarification sir @Ikshvaku

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru Yeah I believe in Vedanta, but I don't agree with their theory on the eternality of Vedic sentences. It doesn't make any sense given the scientific knowledge we have today about cultures and how languages change over time. The Vedas are just like any other culture's ancient text, and have clear indications of being written by priests, in north India, at a certain time, with certain technology, in a certain context, etc.

Comment: Thankyou sir ! @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 0):

There is one origin story of Shudras attributed to Vishvakarma. This will at least give an origin story to the artisans among Shudras, though not to others like cowherds, boatsmen, etc.

There is one story of Vishwakarma and Ghrtachi apsara cursing each other to be born on earth as a Brahmin and Shudra (cowherd caste) respectively. With their union these 9 sons were produced.

The story is found in the **[Brahmavaivarta Purana Brahma Khanda Chapter 10](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/n48/mode/1up)**

> Thereafter the lustful woman became pregnant with well-nourished foetus and she gave birth to nine beautiful sons at that very place. O Saunaka, Visvakarma, imparted adequate training in various arts to all his sons and they became intellects, competent valorous and wise. He then entrusting then the jobs of **gardeners, blacksmiths, conch-makers, weavers, potters, carpenters, gold smiths and painters** and also blessed them variously. He then dedicated all of them to the universe and discarding the human body, Visvakarma went to his heavenly abode.

Thereafter, there is a whole list of the origin of other Shudras. Since it is too lengthy, I’m citing a few examples only:

1. Painter + unchaste Shudra woman = Balcony maker
2. Balcony maker (m) + Potter (f) = home maker/ mason
3. Potter (m) + mason (f) = oil crusher
4. go on to describe other Varnasankaras

**Other Shudras whose origin is not mentioned** are (yes there is overlap):

> O best of the Brahmanas, the cowherds, barbers, sweet meat sellers, the weavers, the black smiths, the gold smiths and the traders are known as sat-Sudras 
> -*verses 17-18*

**The basic point of this answer is that for the craftsmen, Vishwakarma was their originator. They still revere him in many parts of India and call themselves the Vishwakarma caste.**