# What was the name of the first Vaishya?

Tags: varna, vaishya

Bhragu, Vashishta etc. seems to be the first Brahmins.

Priyavrata and Uttānapāda seems to be the first Kshatriyas.

**Is there any mention about the first Vaisya either in guna based or birth based varna system?**

EDIT:

I have removed Shudra part as it's already asked in [Who was the first śūdra to be born or appear on Earth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31824/12304) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was the first śūdra to be born or appear on Earth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/who-was-the-first-%c5%9bu%cc%84dra-to-be-born-or-appear-on-earth)

Comment: @sv. Edited my Q...

Comment: @sv. Also ur Q specifically demanded answer for birth based while i m ok to have answer from both...if you can edit ur Q and remove this constraint and mention brahmin, Kashtriya, Vaishya in title (which u mentioned in body now) this Q can be closed.. :)

Comment: No tag for Vaisya while there are for Brahmins, Ksatriyas and Sudras

Comment: @Rickross yeah.. that's why i didn't add those tags..i feel there should be one tag for Vaishya/Vaisya...

Comment: Read my question again, 'Likewise, who was the first brāhmaṇa, the first kṣatriya and vaiśya to be born?' - so your question is included in mine. I specifically wanted an answer on the basis of birth. You can add 'by birth or guna' or 'born anywhere in the universe' to make yours unique. Also, I used 'history' tag for a reason - because I wanted an answer from a historical standpoint.

Comment: i already mentioned right "either in guna based or birth based" ..also i don't want answer from historical point of view...

Comment: To prevent a mass upheaval of the Vaishyas from occurring I created the tag :P. We can now add it to many old questions where it is needed. @YDS