# Are the first/early members of each varna mentioned in the scriptures?

Tags: scripture, varna, varnashrama

[Verse 1.31 from the Manu Smriti](https://www.hinduismfacts.org/hindu-scriptures-and-holy-books/manusmriti/chapter-i/)

> But for the sake of the prosperity of the worlds he caused the Brahmana, the Kshatriya, the Vaisya, and the Sudra to proceed from his mouth, his arms, his thighs, and his feet.

is often cited as the origin myth of the four varnas. Does any text mention the first or some very early members of each varna?

Comment: Related: [Who was the first Shudra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31824/12304) and [What was the name of the first Vaishya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/what-was-the-name-of-the-first-vaishya)

Comment: @Archit The answer to [Who was the first Shudra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/who-was-the-first-%c5%9bu%cc%84dra-to-be-born-or-appear-on-earth) refers to 47:9 in https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp040.html. 44:1 and 45:4 in the same document cast the former into doubt. The second question was never answered.

Comment: no sorry please don’t misunderstand. I meant they’re related. Or half duplicate. You can have a look at them too. If any duplicate part is there then you can cut it off :)

Comment: @Archit Thanks for clarifying your exact intention. You have my gratitude for bringing these two other questions to my notice.