# I want a commentary on Parashara Smriti 1:25?

Tags: commentary, parashara-smriti

Can somebody find the commentary by Madhavacharya (Vidyaranya) on verse 1.25 of the Parashara Smriti?

The translation of the verse is:

> " In the Krita, one should quit a country itself ; one should quit a
> village in the Treta ; in the Dvapara (one should shun) only the
> particular family ; but in the Kali, one should shun the perpetrator
> alone (of an offence).

Comment: "25. " In the Krita, one should quit a country itself ; one
should quit a village in the Treta ; in the Dvapara (one
should shun) only the particular family ; but in the Kali, one
should shun the perpetrator alone (of an offence)." --- On this verse?

Comment: The PDF that I am quoting from has commentary by Madhava but on this particular verse there is no commentary. The verse is clear enough so why do you need a commentary?

Comment: I taught it as commentary

Comment: But this verse is telling about chandala

Comment: For example in pratiloma message only the brahmin women and shudra men will be chandala . the Born child will not be chandala

Comment: Bez according to that verse shun is for alone not to family

Comment: Yes in Kali Yuga one should shun only the sinner not even his family members. But the requirements are stricter as we move back the Yugas.

Comment: Can you tell first shudra name

Comment: No I don't know the name. For the first Shudra see - (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31824/4732) and even for the first Vaishya a question was asked (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/what-was-the-name-of-the-first-vaishya)

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard any Maadhwa saints talking about Shri-Madhavacharya writing commentary for Parashara smriti. Here is my level of understanding of that verse and actual meaning could be slightly different. God knows better!! I do not know anything!! :

In a village if there are many atheists and unclean people in the Treta Yuga, he should not stay in that village. Because the resources like water have to be shared in a village. Even if one is spiritual he will become contaminated by their presence in the village. In other Yugas the field (where the influence is there) of contamination varied. But in Kaliyuga there is no such contamination. The following line says that untouchability does not apply in Kaliyuga even if there are atheists and unclean people living in your colony or village or family (you should just avoid interacting with them (too much)):

in the Kali, one should shun the perpetrator alone (of an offence).)

Another verse on the same line from the Parashara smriti talks about field of untouchability in a different way:

” In the Krita sin is incurred by one who converses (with a sinner) ; in the Treta by one who touches (the sinful man) ; in the Dvapara by taking the sinner’s food ; in the Kali by a (sinful) act (alone).

Comment: Madhavacharya is different dvaita madhvacharya