# Recommended balance of strength amongst Varnas in an ideal world

Tags: caste-system, varna

Varna system classifies our society  largely into four social groups. Each varna has it's own strength and there is lot of interdependence between them. Hence, it's common sense to state that if one of the varnas rises too much, the society will lose out on benefits of having other varnas. Therefore, I'd like to know if **there are any scriptural recommendations to maintain an ideal ratio between strength / count of varnas in an ideal society**. Scope of my question is both at small scale like Village and large scale like Rashtra.

Comment: It's also possible that such a ratio changed as yuga progressed, as someone mentioned here that first shudra was born only in Treta [Who was the first śūdra to be born or appear on Earth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31824/3881)

Comment: Surely having everyone be born Brahmanas (well "destined" to be Brahmanas as it takes a while for Brahmana traits to manifest) is ideal, as going down Varna is very easy if you need others, but not the other way around.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa ji, If society is only comprised of Brahmans, will they engage in wealth creation? Will they fight with arms? Can society survive without these activities? Typically these activities are not associated with Brahmans. Also, is it prescribed anywhere to aspire to be Brahmins (like a recommendation)? Do let me know. I think the answer could also vary depending upon what world we are living in (Eg, mlechhas  in high numbers in neighbourhood means more kshatriyas needed to tackle them, I guess)

Comment: Brahmanas can do those things if needed. They could also easily lose their Varna. Thus, everyone being born from Brahmanas is ideal.

Comment: Ideally everyone would be born from embryos raised outside the womb and be born from Brahmanas. Human technology just hasn't reached a point where that is feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scriptures state that Vaishyas are meant to be numerous, and Shudras are not.

From the Purusha Suktam of the Taittiriya Samhita of the Krishna Yajur Veda:

> Prajapati [or Purusha] desired, 'May I have offspring.' He meted out the Trivrt from his mouth. After it the god Agni was created, the Gayatri metre, the Rathantara Saman, of men the Brahman, of cattle the goat; therefore are they the chief, for they were produced from the mouth. From the breast and arms he meted out the Pañcadaça Stoma. After it the god Indra was created, the Tristubh metre, the Brhat Saman, of men the Rajanya, of cattle the sheep. Therefore they are strong, for they were created from strength. From the middle he meted out the Saptadaça Stoma. **After it the All-gods as deities were created, the Jagati metre, the Vairupa Saman, of men the Vaiçya, of cattle cows.** Therefore are they to be eaten, for they were created from the receptacle of food. **Therefore are they more numerous than others, for they were created after the most numerous of the gods.** From his feet he meted out the Ekavinça Stoma. After it the Anustubh metre was created, the Vairaja Saman, of men the Çudra, of cattle the horse. Therefore the two, the horse and the Çudra, are dependent on others. Therefore the Çudra is not fit for the sacrifice, for he was not created after any gods. Therefore they depend on their feet, for they were created from the feet.

As for Shudras:

> 8.22. That kingdom where there is a majority of Śūdras, which is infested with non-believers and destitute of twice-born people, quickly perishes entirely, becoming afflicted by famine and disease.
>
> Manu Smriti

More Shudras are easily created when dvijas do not follow their dharma. So, dvijas are meant to follow their dharma to preserve the ratio.